# Calculate the Burning Time for a Lamp

Tags: probability, self-study, exponential-distribution

If you have a lamp with burning time 4000 hours. If the time goes forward until the lamp will be destroyed the exponential distribution is 3675 hours, what is the probability of a lamp to be working at least 4000 hours?

I don't know how to calculate in order to achieve the result?

I have read the document about calculation but still I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This [PDF link](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~riczw/stat330s11/lecture/lec13.pdf) may be useful to you.

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please use the homework tag, and people will still try to help - but in more of a guiding rather than answering-for-you way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let X denote the random time at which the lamp fails. 
X is a random variable with the exponential distribution.

All this means is that the probability that X fails after $x$ hours is given by:
$$P(X>x) = e^{-\lambda x}$$ where $\lambda$ is the parameter for the exponential distribution.

In our case, $\lambda = \frac{1}{3675}$ and $x = 4000$. Thus,
$$P(\{\textrm{of lamp working for at least 4000 hours}\}) = P(X>4000) = e^{-4000/3675} = .3367$$